# Uploading and displaying files from local folder

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, upload, multer

I am very new to NodeJS and web development in general. I am using multer to upload a single file in my web application. This works fine, the file gets uploaded into my "uploads" folder and I'm planning on saving this path in my database so that I can access this file. The problem that I'm having is displaying it (it's an image).

The files are saved as follows: 
[image]

I'm not sure which path to save in my database. Should it be uploads/2e3546b428931124164022e5d1d9310e? or do I need an extension for it.

The JSON object for the file looks like this:

```
{ fieldname: 'mapImage',
  originalname: 'office-wallpaper-2.png',
  encoding: '7bit',
  mimetype: 'image/png',
  destination: 'uploads/',
  filename: '2e3546b428931124164022e5d1d9310e',
  path: 'uploads/2e3546b428931124164022e5d1d9310e',
  size: 736807 }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to rename your file before uploading it.
One simple way to do it is the following

```
var storage = multer.diskStorage({
    destination: './public/uploads/',
    filename: function(req, file, cb) {
        crypto.pseudoRandomBytes(16, function(err, raw) {
            if (err) return cb(err);

            cb(null, raw.toString('hex') + path.extname(file.originalname));
        })
    }
})

var upload = multer({
    storage: storage
})
```

then save the filename into your database